# Adding Basic shape left/right arrow as a clickable previous/next button

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking at writing a little bit of VBA code that will change displayed worksheet to the previous or next sheet in the order of the tabs.

I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376995/excel-vba-insert-arrow-macro) which talks about adding an arrow, but its more like a leader arrow (red in the picture).

[image: example 1]

I want to add the LEFT or RIGHT arrow from the Insert ribbon -> illustrations section -> Shapes drop down:

[image: example 2]

The snipit of code I am using is:

```
Dim l As Long
Dim t As Long

l = Range("O3").Left
t = Range("Q3").Top

Item_Estimate_Sheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, t + 89.25, l + 89.25, l, t).Select

With Selection
    With .ShapeRange.Line
        .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Weight = 1.5
    End With
End With
```

What I am hoping to add is something that looks like the following which I added manually:

[image: example 3]

Part B

Avoiding use of select.  I hear on here time and time again that select is to be avoided and its not required.  I tried removing select and when I did this, it caused an error.  A .something seems to be required at the the end of the add shape line.  Is there a better way to do this?

Part C: Is there a way to get the dimensions/ properties of the shape you inserted other than recording a macro at the time of insertion?  (and damn why did I not remember to record a macro)

***UPDATE:***

so I recorded a macro and edited my code as follow:

```
Item_Estimate_Sheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightArrow, 859.5, 35.25, 25.5, 19.5).Select

With Selection
    With .ShapeRange.Line
        .Name = "NEXT"
        .Top = Range("S3").Top
        .Left = Range("S3").Left
        .Width = Range("Q3").Width * 2
        .Height = Range("Q3").Height * 2
    End With
End With
```

when I got rid of the select as follows it threw an error..something about not acceptable method:

```
With Item_Estimate_Sheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightArrow, 859.5, 35.25, 25.5, 19.5)

    With .ShapeRange.Line
        .Name = "NEXT"
        .Top = Range("S3").Top
        .Left = Range("S3").Left
        .Width = Range("Q3").Width * 2
        .Height = Range("Q3").Height * 2
    End With
End With
```

Comment: So are you looking to insert the `msoShapeRightArrow` and `msoShapeLeftArrow` on each worksheet in your workbook through VBA on the same position with predefined measurements and assign a macro to them that will activate the sheet before/after?

Comment: You can avoid the use of `Selection` by capturing the result of `Shapes.AddConnector` (and removing `.Select`) into a local object variable, or heck the `With` block could even own it: `With Item_Estimate_Sheet.Shapes.AddConnector(...)`

Comment: More or less yes.  I have some code that will create a worksheet for every item selected in a list.  As that sheet gets created I was going to add the arrow shape.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  I thought I had tried it with the with and got an error...been doing a lot of editing so I will have to go back and double check that iteration and see if it was nothing else causing issues.

Comment: Removing the `.Select` is key though

Comment: The correct syntax (I think) would be to set a shape object which you can then access it's properties like : `Set shp = Item_Estimate_Sheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightArrow, 859.5, 35.25, 25.5, 19.5)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll put this up, but I'm quite unsure what exactly your aim is with the `.Line` property of the `.ShapeRange` object. So my take on this is to just insert some arrows, assign them a `.Name` and `.OnAction` while further on I grouped them to assign more common properties like `.Fill`.

Obviously it's a draft but you might be able to get some understanding how (I think) it's done.

```
Sub InsertArrows()

Dim rngL As Range, rngR As Range
Dim shpL As Shape, shpR As Shape

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set rngL = sht.Range("B2")
    Set rngR = sht.Range("C2")

    Set shpL = sht.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeLeftArrow, rngL.Left, rngL.Top, rngL.Width, rngL.Height)
    With shpL
        .Name = "Last"
        .OnAction = "LastSheet"
    End With

    Set shpR = sht.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightArrow, rngR.Left, rngR.Top, rngR.Width, rngR.Height)
    With shpR
        .Name = "Next"
        .OnAction = "NextSheet"
    End With

    Set shpRng = sht.Shapes.Range(Array("Last", "Next"))
    With shpRng
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        'More common properties.....
    End With
Next sht

End Sub

Sub LastSheet()
    'Some code to get to the last sheet 
End Sub

Sub NextSheet()
    'Some code to get to the next sheet 
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: JvdV you have the gist of what I am after.  I was chunking my code together from different sources.  What you are showing here reads a heck of a lot nicer and also has the next step for me built of linking the shape to some code in a sub.  I'll try it out when I am back at work tomorrow and have some free time.

Comment: ++ Nice one :) I do this slightly [differently](https://prnt.sc/p4j3sr) :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout Nice screen shot...are those graphics built into Excel or are they a custom graphic?  We were discussing how a graphic can be much easier/quicker to interpret than a bunch of buttons with text on them that need reading.

Comment: @ForwardEd Custome Graphics downloaded from web and the entire "menu shape" is stored in a settings sheet. So basically, no need to create it again and again. Just copy it when the new worksheet is created.

Comment: I would go with `"Previous"` instead of `"Last"`, but otherwise, I concur. Nice answer

Comment: @SiddharthRout  I just want to toss your description back in my own words to make sure I have the understanding correct.  The graphic(s) (3 separate buttons or 1 big button?) are placed in a worksheet that is stored in the file and probably hidden.  When the buttons need to be added to a worksheet, they are simply referenced from that storage sheet using some modified code that does something similar to add shape?

Comment: @ForwardEd: The 3 buttons and the rectangle are a group. They already are connected to the relevant macros. They are placed in a hidden sheet. When a new sheet is added, I simply copy the shape(group) and paste it in the new sheet. As simple as that. Let me know if you want me to post an answer. (Obviously it doesn't answer your question but can be an alternative)

Comment: @SiddharthRout would love to see it as an alternative if you don't mind.  Even if I do not use it directly, I am sure I will learn a new technique or two.  May even be helpful to some futr user that stumbles on this Q.

Comment: @SiddharthRout No rush.  I just had a stack of CAD drawings dumped on my desk so I will be busy with actual work related stuff for a good chunk of the dat now.  Wont get back to tinkering with coding for 4 hours or more.

Comment: @JvdV Because I am inserting the Navigation arrows as the sheet is created, I am dropping the for each loop.  Thank you for including that as FOR EACH for whatever reason tends to be a stumbling block for me and I avoid using it.  I was not familiar with the VBA Array("Last","Next")  So I definitely learned something new there and I can see this being useful on some other things I have done.  Especially for initializing an array it a known setup.  I have decided to leave your code a a standalone sub which I will call from the INSEert SHEET routine and I will just pass it the SHT and ref cells.

Comment: @ForwardEd, that seems to me like a very nice way to implement things! Well done :)

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: As mentioned in the comments this is not an answer but on OPs request, I am posting this alternative.

For demonstration purpose I have two sheets in a workbook. One is called **HOME** and the other is called **SETTINGS**. *Link to Sample File is given at the end of the post*

I have downloaded 3 shapes from the web. Feel free to choose any other images.

1. [Home Button](https://www.kissclipart.com/home-button-html-clipart-button-computer-icons-cli-2ecg51/)
2. [Next Button](https://pixabay.com/vectors/arrow-button-navigation-right-blue-30330/)
3. [Back Button](https://imgbin.com/png/ExRunE8z/arrow-button-computer-icons-png)

Paste this code in a module

```
Option Explicit

Dim thisSheetCount As Long
Dim nextSheetCount As Long
Dim totSheetCount As Long

Sub InsertNewSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsSettings As Worksheet
    Dim shpOrig As Shape, shpN As Shape

    Set wsSettings = Sheet1
    Set shpOrig = wsSettings.Shapes("MyMenu")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

    shpOrig.Copy
    ws.Paste

    Set shpN = ws.Shapes(1)
    With shpN
        .Top = shpOrig.Top
        .Left = shpOrig.Left
    End With
    DoEvents
    [A1].Activate
End Sub

Sub NextSheet()
    thisSheetCount = ActiveSheet.Index
    totSheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    nextSheetCount = thisSheetCount + 1

    If nextSheetCount > totSheetCount Then
        MsgBox "No more sheets"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do While nextSheetCount <= totSheetCount
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nextSheetCount).Visible = False Then
            nextSheetCount = nextSheetCount + 1
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nextSheetCount).Activate
            Exit Do
        End If

        If nextSheetCount > totSheetCount Then
            MsgBox "No more visible sheets found"
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Sub PrevSheet()
    thisSheetCount = ActiveSheet.Index
    nextSheetCount = thisSheetCount - 1

    If nextSheetCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No more sheets"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do While nextSheetCount >= 1
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nextSheetCount).Visible = False Then
            nextSheetCount = nextSheetCount - 1
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nextSheetCount).Activate
            Exit Do
        End If

        If nextSheetCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No more visible sheets found"
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Sub HomeSheet()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Activate
End Sub
```

Next I insert a rectangle shape in **SETTINGS** sheet. Then I insert the 3 shapes and resize them as shown below

[image]

Right click on the **previous** button and click on *Assign Macro*. Connect it to `Sub PrevSheet()`. Similarly, connect **next** button to `Sub NextSheet()` and finally connect **home** button to `Sub HomeSheet()`

Next, group the Shapes. Call them **MyMenu** or whatever you want. I will use **MyMenu** for demonstration purpose.

Next Copy the shape and paste it in the **HOME** Sheet. Ungroup the shape and delete the **previous** and the **home** button. **HOME** sheet is supposed to be the left most sheet and should always remain visible.

Insert a button in the **HOME** sheet and let's call it "Insert New Sheet". Assign `Sub InsertNewSheet()` to this button.

[image]

Hide the **SETTINGS** Sheet and we are done.

To test it simply click on the `Insert New Sheet` button.

One thing that I would like to point out regarding the **Next** and the **Previous** button code is that, it has been tweaked to work only for visible workssheets. For example: Insert 4 worksheets and hide the 3rd one. Go to the 2nd sheet and click on next button. See what happens. Also check what happens when you click on the next button in the last worksheet.

**Screenshot in action**

[image]

Sample File can be downloaded from [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1u9njlyupbwt39r/Shapes%20Menu%20Example.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  Its a nice easy read to follow.  I have not had a chance to play with it yet.  I have not looked into the previous/next routines yet as I was thinking I would need to make some adjustments as I was guessing +1/-1 to the index would not work in my case.  I had not considered hidden sheets so thanks for putting that on my radar.  In my case sheet can be added a any time, but they get sorted alphabetically.  Meaning the 17th sheet to be created may wind up being the 3rd sheet in the tabs list.

Comment: I was assuming the worksheet index was the same as list on the left when you are in the VBA editor.  oh and to top it off, I have an exception list for the sort routine so about 3-4 sheets are not included in the sort and are locked as first few sheets and last few sheets.  Fun stuff to wrap my head around when I have time to sit down and think about it.

Comment: Good news...apparently my understanding of sheet index number and the way they are displayed in the project menu are completely different.  Life just become easier!  Again thanks for showing me this approach.

Comment: What is the purpose of the DoEvents line after adjusting the position of the shape?

Comment: Just giving Excel time. Usually it would not be required here but becuase the `.Activate` I wanted Excel to finish whatever it is doing.